# Error with starting PostgreSQL database on macOS

Tags: macos, postgresql

I am running the latest version of macOS Sierra and I installed PostgreSQL via brew. Then I ran the command:

```
pg_ctl -D /Users/tmo/PSQL-data -l logfile start
```

but received for output:

```
waiting for server to start..../bin/sh: logfile: Permission denied
 stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

**EDIT:** After restarting my operating system and rerunning the command... I'm now receiving a slightly modified output... but the modification is significant.

```
waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
```

1. Where is the "log output" stored?
2. How do I make this command work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be one of two things, that I can see:

1. A typo in your database path:

   - /Users/tmo/PSQL-data  --> /Users/tmp/PSQL-data
2. If the above was just a transcription error, I would guess that your postgres user doesn't have write access to the directory where you are setting the logfile.  The argument following the `-l` switch tells PG where to save the logfile. When you don't provide the `-l` switch with a path, but just a filename, it will use the same dir you use to specify the database cluster (with the -D flag).  So in this case, PG is trying to write to /Users/tmp/PSQL-data/logfile, and getting a permission error.

To fix this, I would try:

- If the directory /Users/tmp/PSQL-data/ doesn't exist:

  ```
  sudo mkdir /Users/tmp/PSQL-data
  ```
- Then create the logfile manually:

  ```
  sudo touch /Users/tmp/PSQL-data/logfile
  ```
- Then make the postgres user own the file (I'm assuming user is `postgres` here)

  ```
  sudo chown postgres /Users/tmp/PSQL-data/logfile
  ```

Try again, and hopefully you can launch the server.

Caveat: I'm not a macOS user, so I'm not sure how the /tmp folder behaves.  If it is periodically cleared, you may want to specify a different logfile location, so that you don't need to create and chown the file each time you need to launch the cluster.

Comment: "When you don't provide the -l switch with a path, but just a filename, it will use the same dir you use to specify the database cluster (with the -D flag)."
In my experience it uses the current directory instead.